# pjsip 2.0.1 compilation for MacOS

Tags: macos, pjsip

i am trying to compile pjsip 2.0.1 for MacOS. But after doing make i m getting following error.

```
framework CoreFoundation VideoDecodeAcceleration QuartzCore -lbz2 -lz    
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: VideoDecodeAcceleration: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: QuartzCore: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: VideoDecodeAcceleration: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: QuartzCore: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjlib-test-i386-apple-darwin10.8.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjlib-test] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

i installed all the dependencies using following shell script
Use URL https://gist.github.com/2049603 to download the script.

and following steps i m using to compile the pjsip for MacOS

```
./configure
make dep
make clean
make
```

But i am getting above error. I tried to post the problem to pjsip mailing list, but didn't get any answers, it seems that they are not getting my mail. Please somebody can help, or if possible can somebody post my question to pjsip. This will be a great help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "VideoDecodeAcceleration: No such file or directory" error seems to be related to the video parts.

In case you don't need video, try turning video off by adding `#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO    1` to `config_site.h`.

Comment: The dependecies was not installaed proeprly, i triend again, now it's working fine. Thanks for you reply.